# Animating background color for div not working

Tags: html, css

I have the following CSS:

```
.saving-overlay {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  z-index: 999;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  -webkit-transition: background-color 10s linear;
  -ms-transition: background-color 10s linear;
  transition: background-color 10s linear;
}
```

I want to animate the opacity from `0.0` to `0.8` and this is how I have seen it done on the web. It doesn't seem to be working though. Am I missing something?

Comment: Please show us the HTML this is being applied to in a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can see what is happening and be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

What you have got going currently is nearly there. You need to create an animation and add in some keyframes:

```
animation: mymove 10s linear;
@keyframes mymove {
  from {background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);}
  to {background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use animation css property instead of transition property. Please find the sample code below:

```
.saving-overlay {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  z-index: 999;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0);
  animation: animate 1s infinite;
}


@keyframes animate {
  from {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  }
  to {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  }
}
```

Find the sample test link: https://jsbin.com/xetuboj/edit?html,css,output

Note: you can use infinite or linear based on your requirement.